# How to place an image along an arc after an existing arc in Android

Tags: android, image, draw, paint, ondraw

I'm trying to place an image along an arc in android but cannot quite figure it out. I've attempted to try solutions online, but I haven't found anything that quite does what I'm asking. I've also tried to place the image at an exact x,y coordinates, but it never looks the way it should.

The desired image should look something like this (Pardon the MS paint): https://i.stack.imgur.com/3j5oF.jpg

I've attempted to draw three consecutive arcs and replace the middle arc with a bitmap shader but that proved to not work at all.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.